# A Control ID Could not be found in update panel

Tags: asp.net

I have two text box named as rate and quantity inside a grid view as item template.When I change the rate and quantity value then total amount field must be updated but when I am trying to do that by using update panel I got a error.

This is my Code
Aspx:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gvChallan" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                                     CellPadding="3" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                                     BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" Font-Size="Small"
                                    BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" ShowFooter="True"  Width="950px" >
                                   <Columns>
                      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upqty" runat="server"  UpdateMode="Conditional" RenderMode="Inline">
                                                <Triggers>
                                                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="drpproduct" EventName="TextChanged" />
                                                </Triggers>
                                            <ContentTemplate>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtquantity" runat="server" MaxLength="5" CssClass="textb"
                                                 Width="70px" OnTextChanged="QtyChanged" AutoPostBack="true" </asp:TextBox>
                                            </ContentTemplate>
                                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <HeaderStyle Width="70px" />
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rate">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                             <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpRate" runat="server"  UpdateMode="Conditional" RenderMode="Inline">
                                                <Triggers>
                                                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="drpsubitem" EventName="TextChanged" />
                                                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="drpproduct" EventName="TextChanged" />
                                                </Triggers>
                                            <ContentTemplate>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtrate" runat="server" CssClass="textb" Width="70px" MaxLength="5" OnTextChanged="RateChanged" AutoPostBack="true" ></asp:TextBox>
                                            </ContentTemplate>
                                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    <HeaderStyle Width="70px" />
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                             <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpAmount" runat="server"  UpdateMode="Conditional" RenderMode="Inline">
                                                <Triggers>
                                                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="drpproduct" EventName="TextChanged" />
                                                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="drpsubitem" EventName="TextChanged" />
                                                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtrate" EventName="TextChanged" />
                                                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtquantity" EventName="TextChanged" />
                                                </Triggers>
                                            <ContentTemplate>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtamt" runat="server" OnTextChanged="AmtChanged" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="textb" Width="80px" MaxLength="20" ></asp:TextBox>
                                            </ContentTemplate>


                                        </asp:UpdatePanel>

                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        </Columns>



                                        <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
                                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                        <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                        <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" />
                                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB" />
                                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E" />

                                </asp:GridView>
```

cs code :

```
  protected void QtyChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)drpsubitem.NamingContainer;
    TextBox prate = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtrate");
    TextBox pqty = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtquantity");
    TextBox pamt = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtamt");
    pamt.Text = Convert.ToString(float.Parse(prate.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(pqty.Text));
    float gvamt = 0;
    foreach (GridViewRow g1 in gvChallan.Rows)
    {
        TextBox txtgvamt = (TextBox)g1.FindControl("txtamt");
        gvamt = gvamt + float.Parse(txtgvamt.Text);
    }
    txttotamt.Text = Convert.ToString(gvamt);

}

protected void RateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)drpsubitem.NamingContainer;
    TextBox prate = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtrate");
    TextBox pqty = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtquantity");
    TextBox pamt = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtamt");
    pamt.Text = Convert.ToString(float.Parse(prate.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(pqty.Text));
      float gvamt = 0;
    foreach (GridViewRow g1 in gvChallan.Rows)
    {
        TextBox txtgvamt = (TextBox)g1.FindControl("txtamt");
        gvamt = gvamt + float.Parse(txtgvamt.Text);
    }
    txttotamt.Text = Convert.ToString(gvamt);


}
```

Comment: Try to find the `UpdatePanel` within the `Row` then find the `TextView` inside that.

Comment: no no thats the copy mistake i have added in my code

Comment: And what error do you get?

Comment: A control with ID 'txtrate' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'uptotamt'.

Comment: this is the error i am getting every time.The logic is simple i am creating a invoice web form in which there is product drop down list depending on the product rate will be fetch from database and based on the quantity amount field will be updated.rate is changing according to text change event in dropdown but total amount is not refelecting in total amount text box after the quantity chage.

Comment: is anyone there to solve my problem???

Comment: What i meant was something like this `(TextView)row.FindControl("upqty").FindControl("txtquantity")`

Comment: replace `row.FindControl("txtquantity")` with it and see if solves the problem _for this particular textbox only_

Comment: i have eddite the text <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtrate" EventName="TextChanged" /> with <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="(gvChallan)row.FindControl("upqty").FindControl("txtquantity")" EventName="TextChanged" /> but it also gives another error

Comment: Leaving the `aspx` code as you orignally posted it, replace the `cs` code with this: http://pastebin.com/CdF3BaZc

Comment: Can you show how do you retrieve 'drpsubitem' variable?